# Python PyQt: how to get mouse position x and y

Tags: python, pyqt

I'm trying to get the x and y position from a QCursor variable

```
def run(self):
   pos = QCursor.pos()
   print(pos.toPoint())
```

this prints the following:

> PyQt6.QtCore.QPoint(523, 590)

if i try to print pos.x or pos.y it prints the following:

> <built-in method x of QPoint object at 0x7fe85027b0b0

When i googled i found out the mapFromGlobal() method, but i couldn't make it work.
Is there any way to get X and Y values?

thanks

Comment: All Qt property *getters* (except where explicitly written) are always callables. Use the parentheses to call the getter and get the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pos.x` and `pos.y` are methods, not properties so they need to be called.

try:

```
pos.x()
pos.y()
```

Anytime you print an object in python and it looks like `<built-in method ...` that means the attribute is a method and needs to be invoked.

Answer (score -1):

You are printing the PyQt6 object class.

If you are calling the X and Y functions from the QPoint class correctly and it won't work then try converting the X and Y values to a string.